# How does udev talk to daemons like NetworkManager?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, udev, networkmanager, netlink

On [udev wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev), it has this picture:

`Kernel -> udev -> NetworkManager <-> DBus <-> Firefox`.

Kernel sends uevents to udevd via netlink sockets. NetworkManager talks to Firefox via dbus. All good.

What is the communication mechanism between udev (I assume it is udevd daemon) and NetworkManager? I can see besides NETLINK_ROUTE, which is necessary to configure links/routes etc, the NetworkManager opens several NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT sockets itself. Does that mean the wiki picture is outdated, and the NetworkManager listens/gather device information directly from kernel uevents?

Otherwise, if udevd is supposedly responsible to disseminate all device related information to all user applications (daemons), how does it do it? Maybe a unix domain socket, if so what's the name of it?

And, what does `/run/udev/control` do exactly?